# How to append a python list to another list (Series) of a polars-dataframe?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a polars dataframe like this:

`test=pl.DataFrame({"myColumn": [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]})`

Now i would like to append list elements from another list, lets say `[4,5]` to each of the entries, so to get `[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]`

Q1: How would that be done ?
Q2: What would be an approach to make it fast ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polars Series/columns of dtype `List` have a `.list` namespace. You can use the `list.concat` method to append a list.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"my_column": [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]})
df.with_column(pl.col("my_column").list.concat([4, 5]))
```

The output is:

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────────┐
│ my_column     │
│ ---           │
│ list [i64]    │
╞═══════════════╡
│ [1, 2, ... 5] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [1, 2, ... 5] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [1, 2, ... 5] │
└───────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I haven't run a benchmark, but i can already tell, that for my purpose it is fast enough.

Comment: Next release a faster solution will be available. Then I will update my answer.

Comment: did you implement the faster solution? I'd be interested to know

Comment: Since polars 0.18.0 `.arr` is replaced by `.list`. Hence, `df.with_column(pl.col("my_column").arr.concat([4, 5]))` is now `df.with_columns(pl.col("my_column").list.concat([4, 5]))`