# How can I append or concatenate two dataframes in python polars?

Tags: python, concatenation, append, python-polars

I see it's possible to append using the series namespace (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70599059/5363883). What I'm wondering is if there is a similar method for appending or concatenating DataFrames.

In `pandas` historically it could be done with `df1.append(df2)`. However that method is being deprecated (if it hasn't already been deprecated) for `pd.concat([df1, df2])`.

df1

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

df2

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

res

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

Comment: Closest thing I could find that doesn't seem documented in the cookbook would be [.extend()](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.extend.html?).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are different `append` strategies depending on your needs.

```py
df1 = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1], "b": [2], "c": [3]})
df2 = pl.DataFrame({"a": [4], "b": [5], "c": [6]})


# new memory slab
new_df = pl.concat([df1, df2], rechunk=True)

# append free (no memory copy)
new_df = df1.vstack(df2)

# try to append in place
df1.extend(df2)
```

To understand the differences, it is important to understand polars memory is immutable `iff` it has any copy.

Copies in polars are free, because it only increments a reference count of the backing memory buffer instead of copying the data itself.

However, if a memory buffer has no copies yet, e.g. the `refcount == 1`, we **can** mutate polars memory.

Knowing this background there are the following ways to append data:

- `concat` -> concatenate all given `DataFrames`. This is sort of a linked list of `DataFrames`. If you pass `rechunk=True`, all memory will be reallocated to contiguous chunks.
- `vstack` -> Adds the data from `other` to `DataFrame` by incrementing a refcount. This is super cheap. It is recommended to call rechunk after many `vstacks`. Or simply use `pl.concat`.
- `extend` This operation copies data. It tries to copy data from other to `DataFrame`. If however the `refcount` of `DataFrame` is larger than `1`. A new buffer of memory is allocated to hold both  `DataFrames`.

Comment: Wow. Not sure how I missed `pl.concat`. Sounds like `rechunk=True` is what I was looking for too.

Comment: if `rechunk=True`, does `concat` copies date to the new allocated memory region? Then what is the difference from `extend`

Comment: @ritchie46 After doing vstack of 2 dfs, if we need to write_ipc the df to disk, is rechunk necessary to be called?

Comment: Is there a way to reserve space ahead of time for appending later, like `Vec::reserve` in the standard library?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [.extend()](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.extend.html?) mutates `df1` to *extend* its memory to `df2`.

```py
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1], "b": [2], "c": [3]})
df2 = pl.DataFrame({"a": [4], "b": [5], "c": [6]})
df1.extend(df2)

┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

This makes sense, but if I wanted to create a totally distinct (in memory too) `df3` I'm guessing it'd be

```py
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1], "b": [2], "c": [3]})
df2 = pl.DataFrame({"a": [4], "b": [5], "c": [6]})

df3 = pl.from_records(df1.to_numpy(), columns=["a", "b", "c"])
df3.extend(df2)

┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Any feedback on less verbose methods would be appreciated.

Comment: Playing around with this, this seems to create extended `df1` as entirely separate from `df2` memory. Correct me if I'm wrong.