# Concatenate/bind polars dataframes in a single dictionary with names

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a dictionary created by importing data from multiple Excel sheets using `polars.read_excel`. I'd like to combine them all, by row, into a single dataframe and preserve the sheet name as a column in the new combined dataframe to record which sheet the observation came from.

I found a solution ([Similar Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654966/how-can-i-append-or-concatenate-two-dataframes-in-python-polars)) that does almost what I'm looking for, but the solution explicitly calls the dataframes. I'm looking for a solution similar to the R Tidyverse solution. The Tidy solution to this type of concatenation would be really simple:

```
df <- list %>% 
    bind_rows(.id = "ID")
```

As I understand it, the most similar Polars function to `bind_rows` would be `concat(how="vertical")`.

Is there something like this available in Polars? Something like the following perhaps:

```
df = dcty.polars.concat(how="vertical")
```

I've found that if I convert the dictionary to a list, the `concat` function works to combine the dataframes, but then I lose the dataframe names.

Sample Data

```py
dcty = {
    "df1": pl.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': ["a", "b"]}),
    "df2": pl.DataFrame({'col1': [3, 4], 'col2': ["c", "d"]}),
}
```

Expected Output:

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ sheet│
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ a    ┆ df1  │
│ 2    ┆ b    ┆ df1  │
│ 3    ┆ c    ┆ df2  │
│ 4    ┆ d    ┆ df2  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output? (using `dict` as a variable name makes the example rather confusing)

Comment: @jqurious I added the expected output and changed the name of the sample output.

Comment: I don't really understand, you mention `concat` but that *is* the answer so why didn't it work for you? ie `pl.concat([df1, df2])`

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I want to concatenate all dataframes in a dictionary. Something like: `pl.concat(dcty)`, or preferable with piping, as in `dcty.pl.concat()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the sample input, this generates the expected output:

```py
pl.concat([df.with_columns(sheet=pl.lit(name)) for name, df in dcty.items()])
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ sheet │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64  ┆ str  ┆ str   │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1    ┆ a    ┆ df1   │
│ 2    ┆ b    ┆ df1   │
│ 3    ┆ c    ┆ df2   │
│ 4    ┆ d    ┆ df2   │
└──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Explanation:

- `.with_columns` adds a new column to the original dataframes with the "sheet names" as literals.
- `pl.concat` concatenates dataframes (vertically by default). See [docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html) for details.

Comment: Assuming your dataframes are in a dictionary (`dfs`) where the key is the sheet name and the values are the dataframes: `pl.concat([df.with_columns(sheet=pl.lit(sheet_name)) for sheet_name, df in dfs.items()])`

Comment: I believe this is the best answer that currently exists. Future enhancements to polars may create a more straightforward functionality. Thanks!