# Polars map on list type operates on all rows instead of single row

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

There is a conundrum I cannot solve in Polars:

This behaves as expected:

```
print(pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "int1": [1, 2, 3],
            "int2": [3, 2, 1]
        }
        )
     .with_columns(pl.struct(['int1', 'int2'])
                   .map(lambda x: x.struct.field('int1') + x.struct.field('int2')).alias('int3'))
    )
)
```

output:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ int1 ┆ int2 ┆ int3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 3    ┆ 4    │
│ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ 4    │
│ 3    ┆ 1    ┆ 4    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Yet this does not:

```
print(pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "int1": [[1], [2], [3]],
            "int2": [[3], [2], [1]]
        }
        )
     .with_columns(pl.struct(['int1', 'int2'])
                   .map(lambda x: x.struct.field('int1').to_list() + x.struct.field('int2').to_list()).alias('int3'))
    )
```

output:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────────────┐
│ int1      ┆ int2      ┆ int3              │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---               │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[list[i64]]   │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ [1]       ┆ [3]       ┆ [[1], [2], … [1]] │
│ [2]       ┆ [2]       ┆ [[1], [2], … [1]] │
│ [3]       ┆ [1]       ┆ [[1], [2], … [1]] │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Why am I getting a list of lists in the second case? If it wasn't clear - I wanted the lambda to concatenate between the values in `int1` and `int2`.
This is the output I was expecting:

```
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ int1      ┆ int2      ┆ int3      │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1]       ┆ [3]       ┆ [1, 3]    │
│ [2]       ┆ [2]       ┆ [2, 2]    │
│ [3]       ┆ [1]       ┆ [3, 1]    │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

It seems that the lambda in the second case is receiving all rows as input, but I want to operate only on a single row each time!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591912/how-to-append-a-python-list-to-another-list-series-of-a-polars-dataframe

Comment: Operating on a row at a time is definitely a big anti-pattern of polars and you should avoid it whenever possible as it circumvents all the optimizations that make it fast and efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think your problem is that you confuse `.map` and `.apply`. Like it is written in the documentation "A map passes the Series backed by the expression as is." Which means your function is transforming the whole `Series` to `List` and then adding them up.
Whereas `.apply` works elementwise.
The differences of these two functions are nicely explained in the user guide [see here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/custom_functions.html?highlight=map#to-map-or-to-apply)

So to get your wanted result you have to do this:

```
print(
    pl.DataFrame({"int1": [[1], [2], [3]], "int2": [[3], [2], [1]]}).with_columns(
        pl.struct(["int1", "int2"]).apply(lambda x: x["int1"] + x["int2"]).alias("int3")
    )
)



shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ int1      ┆ int2      ┆ int3      │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1]       ┆ [3]       ┆ [1, 3]    │
│ [2]       ┆ [2]       ┆ [2, 2]    │
│ [3]       ┆ [1]       ┆ [3, 1]    │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "int1": [[1], [2], [3]],
            "int2": [[3], [2], [1]]
        }
        )


out = df.with_columns(pl.col("int1").arr.concat(pl.col("int2")).alias("a + b"))

print(out)

----------------------
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ int1      ┆ int2      ┆ a + b     │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1]       ┆ [3]       ┆ [1, 3]    │
│ [2]       ┆ [2]       ┆ [2, 2]    │
│ [3]       ┆ [1]       ┆ [3, 1]    │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the idiomatic way of combining two (or more) columns into a single list column is to use `concat_list`

```
pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "int1": [1, 2, 3],
            "int2": [3, 2, 1]
        }
        ) \
    .with_columns(int3=pl.concat_list(pl.col('int1'), pl.col('int2')))

shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ int1 ┆ int2 ┆ int3      │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ list[i64] │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 3    ┆ [1, 3]    │
│ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ [2, 2]    │
│ 3    ┆ 1    ┆ [3, 1]    │
└──────┴──────┴───────────┘
```